# How to make Certificate Authority issue my requests?

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, domaincontroller

I have DC for development. In DC I have installed Certificate Authority. 
Then from web server, in IIS, I'm trying to add server certificate.

In the last step, when I finish the wizard and certificate request is submitted to DC, it is not issued.
[image: Create Certificate screenshot]

When I go to DC, I can see requests under Pending requests. I can now issue or deny certificate, but it is already too late. 
[image: Server Manager screenshot]

**Is it possible to automatically issue my requests? Or, can I add the later issued request in my web server?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Double click issued certificate (in DC).
2. In Details tab click "Copy to file"
3. Run wizard and export .cer file
4. Copy .cer file to web server
5. In web server, in IIS under Server Certificates, right click and Complete Certificate Request…
6. Import .cer file, add meaningful name